# Grid.IsSharedSizeScope equivalent for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Is there any kind of simple (non-custom-coded) equivalent to WPFs `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` in Windows 8/RT XAML?

I have `ListViewItem`s that are divided into 3 horizontal sections and those 3 columns need to be aligned (to the widest width each) to all the bound `ListViewItem`.

Comment: Todd you can go throught the metro solution :) worked for me . If any more modifications required let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that was for wpf I found a Metro solution to the problem. Ill paste the entire code in here. :)

```
<Page.Resources>        
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1"  >
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Gray">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name1}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name2}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name3}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">        
    <ListView Name="MyList" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Yellow" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}">  
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>                
            <ItemsPanelTemplate
                <!-- Here is the panel that will contain the items -->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Pink" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

and the code behind . just to give a try did not use MVVM

Here's the cs

```
        List<test> li = new List<test>();
    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
    /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            li.Add(new test()
            {
                Name1 = "Anobik1" + i.ToString(),
                Name2 = "Anobik1"                    +i.ToString(),
                Name3 = "Anobik1"                    +i.ToString()
            });
        }
        MyList.ItemsSource = li;
    }
```

and the class that I bind was as follows

```
class test
{
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    public string Name3 { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Ok and last answer I did not edit since this was a bit too long and wanted to show the entire demo i was researching on so that it could benifit you.

Comment: Wow, that's brilliant! Exactly what I needed. Thank you Anobik so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample code how to divide stackpanels inside listview

```xml
<ListView Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MeasuringDeviceCommunicators}"  >
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <!-- Here is the panel that will contain the items -->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName= MyList}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Give a try your content will go inside the three stack panels. While the stackpanel that decides the orientation of the items in list view has been set to meet parents width and grid has been stretched to meet the parents width.

Comment: This was so promising, but it appears it works only in WPF, not in Silverlight or WinRT. on both SL and WRT pages (like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx) it says `For purposes of ElementName binding, ActualWidth does not post updates when it changes (due to its asynchronous and run-time calculated nature). Do not attempt to use ActualWidth as a binding source for an ElementName binding. If you have a scenario that requires updates based on ActualWidth, use a SizeChanged handler.` +1 for the effort though.

Comment: Do I give an attempt to metro xaml also ?

Comment: metro xaml = winrt. I tried there and it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Ok i am seeing if I can find a break :) Ill let you knoe . :)